# Is it grammatically correct to say "I am (feeling) hot"? (hot vs warm)

Tags: word-usage, difference

Definition of *hot* by [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hot?s=t):

> having or giving off heat; having a high temperature:

Definition of *warm* by [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/warm?s=t):

> of or at a moderately high temperature; characterized by comparatively high temperature:

---

Many people argue that you it is wrong to say "I am (feeling) **hot**" and argues that **"hot"** refers to temperature 40℃ and above while **"warm"** refers to temperature 30-40℃.

I personally feel silly to say *"I am (feeling) warm"* because it is the fact that you have been warm all the time (unless the temperature just rose to 30℃ or dropped to 40℃).

I have tried to search about this but to no avail. Although I cannot find a direct comparison explanation ("hot" or "warm"), but I can find individually and confirm that both are grammatically correct.

Comment: Related: [What does "I'm feeling hot" mean?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/49882/what-does-i-am-feeling-hot-mean)

Comment: @CowperKettle, can you point out the relation? I don't see a relation between "hot" as sexual connotation and is it right to use *hot* instead of *warm* to refer to high temperature.

Comment: Anyone who tries to claim that words like ***cold, cool, warm, hot*** can be precisely mapped onto specific temperature ranges is a complete idiot.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, thanks! You should add that as answer. Btw, there are people who mapped it! Look at this Quora answer: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-the-word-warm-and-hot/answer/Varun-Mukati-2?srid=2gEG

Answer (score 3):

First of all, as a speaker of American English, I would rarely say

> I'm feeling hot/warm/cold.

This present progressive use of *to feel* is used for other things, such as

> I'm feeling sick

At any rate, I could say

> I'm hot/warm/cold.

if I wanted to report on my personal status.

But in many situations I would report on the temperature of my environment when I feel hot/warm/cold. Thus

> **It's hot/warm/cold/chilly**  (in/out here). 
>    (Could you fix it so that I'm not hot/warm/cold/chilly?)

So, yes you can say both *It's hot* or *It's warm*. And you can say this to either report a fact

> It's hot. It's 40°.
>
> It's warm. It's 30°.

or to indicate that you *feel* hot or warm. But feeling is subjective, and what is hot to one person may be warm to someone else.

Note I can remark on other facets of my environment, such as

> It's humid/drafty in here.

but I couldn't say

> *I'm humid/drafty

Comment: Hi, I'm inquiring on "hot" and "warm". Would you please cover that too? Perhaps this: "It's hot" vs "It's warm". Is the first one grammatically incorrect? Yes/no please explain. :)

Comment: Both of them are grammatical. I've edited my answer a bit

Answer (score 0):

> To *feel* **hot**.
>
> To *feel* **warm**.

Both of them are correct, but depending on the context you should use one and avoid the other. So it's basically context dependent.

- *WARM* is generally regarded as something that is comfortable, on the other hand *HOT* is something uncomfortable, when it comes to talking about temperature you feel.

**EXAMPLE -**

> By morning she *felt* **hot** and sweaty, as though she was getting the flu.
>
> She held her palms to the oven. It *felt* **warm** but not **hot**.
>
> The room was cold, but under the blanket I *felt* **warm** and **cozy**.
>
> Grace tried to breathe, but the room *felt* **hot** and noisy.